# Comparable and generics

Tags: java, generics, comparable

When this class is created..

```
public static class TreeNode<E extends Comparable<E>>
```

what does the `<E extends Comparable<E>>` mean?

Answer (score 6):

That is a generic constraint.

It means that whatever type you store in the `TreeNode` must implement the `Comparable<E>` interface.

Answer (score 5):

It means that whenever you create an instance of this class like

```
TreeNode<MyClass> myTreeNode = new TreeNode<MyClass>();
```

MyClass must implement Comparable < MyClass >

```
public class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass>
{
      //CODE
}
```

Comment: As Spidy is pointing out, it means that the type, `E`, must also implement `Comparable` (of its own type, which is common). Alternatively, you could support the old, pre-generic style of `E extends Comparable`, but this is less generic and means code will require casting because usage of Comparable will accept `Object` rather than `E`. It's odd syntax, but it just means that the object must implement an interface that happens to require the object itself as its own generic type.

Comment: You had it correct with "implements" -- `Comparable` is an interface.

Comment: Pssh... `Comparable` is an interface.